# How do I set alpha value of a UIView from within the UIViewController? - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, alpha

I'm using the MVC framework for a Swift application, how do I set the alpha value of a UIView from within a function of its UIViewController in Swift 4?

Comment: Will you show your code that you tried?

Comment: I think you need to read more about iOS development and its architecture.

Answer (score 2):

.alpha is used to give the alpha value to any view.

```
view.alpha = 0.5;
```

Here 'view' indicates to the view you have taken. And it can be given any value between 0 - 1.0

Answer (score 1):

```
yourView.alpha = 0.5 // Any value from 0-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the view from Interface Builder and change it's alpha property. Below is the screenshot for the same:

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAtdh.png)

Alternatively, if you have an IBOutlet of that view, then you can change the alpha of that particular view programmatically as well. This can be done by below line of code:

```
yourView.alpha = 0.5 // Value must be between 0 & 1.0
```

Hope this helps!